# Cannot change the width of AlertDialog with custom view in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am absolute beginner to Android. Now I am having a problem with setting the width of default AlertDialog with custom view in Android. It is not resizing the width of the alert dialog. What is wrong with my code ?

This is the view layout of my alert dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/green"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/btn_row_option_done"
        android:text="Done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/lightBlue"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:id="@+id/btn_row_option_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/btn_row_option_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/btn_row_option_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I set the width of the linearLayout to wrap_content.

This is how I am opening the alert dialog in my Java code

```
public void showOptionDialog(final int id)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_option_dialog, null);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
        Boolean isTaskDone = dbHelper.isTaskDone(id);
        Button doneBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_done);
        if(isTaskDone==false)
        {
            doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dbHelper.markAsDone(id);
                    refreshListView();
                    alertDialog.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Marked as done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)doneBtn.getParent();
            viewGroup.removeView(doneBtn);
        }
        Button editBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_edit);
        if(isTaskDone==false)
        {
            editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                    activity.replaceEditTaskFragment(id);
                    alertDialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)editBtn.getParent();
            viewGroup.removeView(editBtn);
        }
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_delete);
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper.deleteTask(id);
                items.remove(optionFocusedItemIndex);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Task deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialog.cancel();
                updateListEmptyText();
            }
        });
        Button cancelBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_cancel);
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setView(view);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

But when the alert dialog is opened, its width is not resized and still showing the default size like in screenshot.

This is the screenshot.

[image]

As you can see, width is nearly full of screen even I did set to wrap_content. I also set something like 300px. It is not working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First make other layout for container and inside it make this linear layout with wrap content. After that you can make your alpha background of the container almost to 0 to be transparent. The dialog inside with the buttons is on the inner layout. For custom dialog you cant use this AlertDialog, make your own activity which behavior is like a dialog.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/ this is example for custom dialog :)

Comment: And this is my example with activity wich is like a dialog. Here is the xml file and you can see the other part https://github.com/Krystev/Internship/blob/master/Android/TextEditor/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_info.xml

Comment: No when I do like this every thing disappear from dialog cause alpha is 0

Comment: Did you try to set other background for the separated views ?

Comment: If I set custom view like in
mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example. How can I set the event  for buttons and I am opening dialog in Fragment

Comment: Just set onClickListeners for every button and inside of the onClick method add what you want to do when the button is pressed

Comment: But I am finding by buttons like this in fragment. view.findViewById() . If I do it , how can I get the view reference to find views by id ?\

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, can you explain?

Comment: `Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
   dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     dialog.dismiss();
    }
   });` Is this what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

set required size here

    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">......</LinearLayout>`

or

`alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(300, 300);`

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
alertDialog.setView(view);
```

To

```
alertDialog.setContentView(view);
```

Here view is the instance of your custom layout.